# Broadcast data bytes through iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ip, cfnetwork

I want to broadcast some data bytes in particular wifi range through my iPhone app...so that every receiver in that particular range will receive that bytes. I am very much new to this concept.

Is there any sample app?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is very interesting for doing socket in Objective-c, either UDP or TCP : http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/

Answer (score 0):

Just send UDP packets to for instance address 224.1.2.3 which is a multicast address. I am not 100% sure where it will go, but if you disable 3G, at least then it should go to WiFi.